# Sorting dictionary keys based on their values

Tags: python, sorting

I have a python dictionary setup like so

```
mydict = { 'a1': ['g',6],
           'a2': ['e',2],
           'a3': ['h',3],
           'a4': ['s',2],
           'a5': ['j',9],
           'a6': ['y',7] }
```

I need to write a function which returns the ordered keys in a list, depending on which column your sorting on so for example if we're sorting on mydict[key][1] (ascending)

I should receive a list back like so

```
['a2', 'a4', 'a3', 'a1', 'a6', 'a5']
```

It mostly works, apart from when you have columns of the same value for multiple keys, eg. 'a2': ['e',2] and 'a4': ['s',2]. In this instance it returns the list like so

```
['a4', 'a4', 'a3', 'a1', 'a6', 'a5']
```

Here's the function I've defined

```
def itlist(table_dict,column_nb,order="A"):
    try:
        keys = table_dict.keys()
        values = [i[column_nb-1] for i in table_dict.values()]
        combo = zip(values,keys)
        valkeys = dict(combo)
        sortedCols = sorted(values) if order=="A" else sorted(values,reverse=True)
        sortedKeys = [valkeys[i] for i in sortedCols]
    except (KeyError, IndexError), e:
        pass
    return sortedKeys
```

And if I want to sort on the numbers column for example it is called like so

```
sortedkeysasc = itmethods.itlist(table,2)
```

So any suggestions?

Paul

Comment: you just need to use the `key` kwarg of the sort function

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Wouldn't it be much easier to use

```
sorted(d, key=lambda k: d[k][1])
```

(with `d` being the dictionary)?

Comment: Yeah, and the iterator's laziness is particularly an advantage too. This solution is better than mine, pity that I can't upvote twice %)

Comment: @ulidtko: The lazines isn't particularly relevant, since `sorted()` will generate the whole list before sorting anyway.  It would be equivalent to use `a = d.keys(); a.sort(key=lambda k: d[k][1])` here, but `sorted(d.keys(), ...)` would create a redundant copy of the list.

Comment: This is neat. Is it possible to do the reverse i.e. sort dictionary values based on keys & return list of value only in 1 line. Basically avoid list comprehension in this `[v for (k,v) in sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda (k, v) : v ) ]`

Comment: @buffer: You can't do the very same thing since you can't look up the key given the value.  Your approach is fine in my opinion (possibly with `key=operator.itemgetter(1)` instead).  Alternatives would be `map(d.get, sorted(d))` or the rather non-obvious `itemgetter(*sorted(d))(d)`.

Comment: @buffer: I just noticed that your code actually sorts by value, not by key, as you say in the text.  If this is what you actually need, you don't look at the keys at all, so simply `sorted(d.itervalues())` does the trick.

Comment: My bad. It should have been `[v for (k,v) in sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda (k, v) : k ) ]`

Comment: @Sven When I try this code (Python 2.7) I get `TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`,  b/c I have a dictionary without lists as values, but ints. So I use `sorted(d.iterkeys(), key=lambda k: d[k])`

Comment: @neuronet: To sort a different data structure than the one in the question, you of course need to adapt the code.  I'd suggest the even more succinct `sorted(d, key=d.get)` for your specific use case.

Answer (score 10):

```
>>> L = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda (k, v): v[1])
>>> L
[('a2', ['e', 2]), ('a4', ['s', 2]), ('a3', ['h', 3]), ('a1', ['g', 6]), ('a6', ['y', 7]), ('a5', ['j', 9])]

>>> map(lambda (k,v): k, L)
['a2', 'a4', 'a3', 'a1', 'a6', 'a5']
```

Here you sort the dictionary items (key-value pairs) using a *key* - callable which establishes a total order on the items.

Then, you just filter out needed values using a `map` with a `lambda` which just selects the key. So you get the needed list of keys.

---

**EDIT:** see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690094/sorting-dictionary-keys-based-on-their-values/4690265#4690265) for a much better solution.

Comment: I'm somewhat partial to `[k for (k,v) in sorted(...)]` as well.

Comment: Blimey very nice thankyou! Much less code than my solution too!

Answer (score 3):

Although there are multiple working answers above, a slight variation / combination of them is the most *pythonic* to me:

```
[k for (k,v) in sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda (k, v): v[1])]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> mydict = { 'a1': ['g',6],
...            'a2': ['e',2],
...            'a3': ['h',3],
...            'a4': ['s',2],
...            'a5': ['j',9],
...            'a6': ['y',7] }
>>> sorted(mydict, key=lambda k:mydict[k][1])
['a2', 'a4', 'a3', 'a1', 'a6', 'a5']
>>> sorted(mydict, key=lambda k:mydict[k][0])
['a2', 'a1', 'a3', 'a5', 'a4', 'a6']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def itlist(table_dict, col, desc=False):
    return [key for (key,val) in
        sorted(
            table_dict.iteritems(),
            key=lambda x:x[1][col-1],
            reverese=desc,
            )
        ]
```