# Sorting dictionary using operator.itemgetter

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

[A question was asked here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690094/sorting-dictionary-keys-based-on-their-values), a few minutes ago, on sorting dictionary keys based on their values.

I just read about the `operator.itemgetter` method of sorting a few days back and decided to try that, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Not that I have any problems with the answers presented to the questions, I just wanted to try this with `operator.itemgetter`.

So the dict was:

```
>>> mydict = { 'a1': ['g',6],
           'a2': ['e',2],
           'a3': ['h',3],
           'a4': ['s',2],
           'a5': ['j',9],
           'a6': ['y',7] }
```

I tried this:

```
>>> l = sorted(mydict.itervalues(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
>>> l
[['e', 2], ['s', 2], ['h', 3], ['g', 6], ['y', 7], ['j', 9]]
```

And this works as I want it to. However, since I don't have the complete dictionary (`mydict.itervalues()`), I tried this:

```
>>> complete = sorted(mydict.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(2))
```

This doesn't work (as I expected it to).

So how do I sort the dict using `operator.itemgetter` and call `itemgetter` on the nested key - value pair.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
In [6]: sorted(mydict.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): operator.itemgetter(1)(v))
Out[6]: 
[('a2', ['e', 2]),
 ('a4', ['s', 2]),
 ('a3', ['h', 3]),
 ('a1', ['g', 6]),
 ('a6', ['y', 7]),
 ('a5', ['j', 9])]
```

The key parameter is always a function that is fed one item from the iterable (`mydict.iteritems()`) at a time. In this case, an item could be something like

```
('a2',['e',2])
```

So we need a function that can take `('a2',['e',2])` as input and return 2.

`lambda (k,v): ...` is an anonymous function which takes one argument -- a 2-tuple -- and unpacks it into `k` and `v`. So when the `lambda` function is applied to our item, `k` would be `'a2'` and `v` would be `['e',2]`.

`lambda (k,v): operator.itemgetter(1)(v)` applied to our item thus returns
`operator.itemgetter(1)(['e',2])`, which "itemgets" the second item in `['e',2]`, which is 2.

Note that `lambda (k,v): operator.itemgetter(1)(v)` is not a good way to code in Python. As gnibbler points out, `operator.itemgetter(1)` is recomputed *for each item*. That's inefficient. The point of using `operator.itemgetter(1)` is to create a function that can be applied many times. You don't want to re-create the function each time. `lambda (k,v): v[1]` is more readable, and faster:

```
In [15]: %timeit sorted(mydict.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): v[1])
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.55 us per loop

In [16]: %timeit sorted(mydict.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): operator.itemgetter(1)(v))
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.2 us per loop
```

Comment: Can you please explain this: `operator.itemgetter(1)(v))`?

Comment: @A A: `operator.itemgetter(1)(v)` is equivalent to `v[1]`.  You can replace just any occurrence of `a[b]` with `operator.itemgetter(b)(a)`, but this is not how *I* did understand your question :)

Comment: Creating an itemgetter is relatively expensive. This creates one for each key in the dict

Comment: for python3 use items instead of iteritems

Comment: Invalid syntax anyway, because `lambda` does not take the tuple.

Comment: I think it would be valuable to put a disclaimer at the top lest the naive Google searcher unwittingly think's it's cool to use that

Answer (score 7):

The answer is -- you can't.  `operator.itemgetter(i)` returns a callable that returns the item `i` of its argument, that is

```
f = operator.itemgetter(i)
f(d) == d[i]
```

it will never return simething like `d[i][j]`.  If you really want to do this in a purely functional style, you can write your own `compose()` function:

```
def compose(f, g):
    return lambda *args: f(g(*args))
```

and use

```
sorted(mydict.iteritems(), key=compose(operator.itemgetter(1),
                                       operator.itemgetter(1)))
```

Note that I did not recommend to do this :)

Comment: `unutbu` has a solution, though it's not clear. We will wait for him to update it.

Answer (score 5):

itemgetter doesn't support nesting ( although attrgetter does)

you'd need to flatten the dict like this

```
sorted(([k]+v for k,v in mydict.iteritems()), key=itemgetter(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Indexing normally a la `kv[1][1]` is faster:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> setup = 'import operator; g = operator.itemgetter(1); '
>>> setup += 'd = {i: list(range(i+2)) for i in range(100)}'
>>> kwargs = {'setup': setup, 'number': 10000}

>>> timeit('sorted(d.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1][1])', **kwargs)
0.5251589557155967

>>> timeit('sorted(d.items(), key=lambda kv: g(kv[1]))', **kwargs)
0.7175205536186695

>>> timeit('sorted(d.items(), key=lambda kv: g(kv)[1])', **kwargs)
0.7915238151326776

>>> timeit('sorted(d.items(), key=lambda kv: g(g(kv)))', **kwargs)
0.9781978335231543
```

Answer (score 0):

The ability to unpack tuple parameters was removed in Python 3: See PEP [3113](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/).

So the accepted answer will not work for people who run python 3.x :

An equivalent solution would be

```
sorted(mydict.items(),key=lambda kv:operator.itemgetter(1)(kv[1]) )
```