# Sort dict by highest value?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've got a dict with string keys and int values. Is there any way I could take this dict and use it to get a list of the keys from highest to lowest value?

Example:

```
>>> myDict = {'seven': 7, 'four': 4, 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'five': 5, 'eight': 8}
>>> myList = myDict.sortNumericallyByKeys
>>> myList
['eight', 'seven', 'five', 'four', 'two', 'one']
```

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ I looked thorough the data structures docs and didn't find anything. Where else could I look?

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ won't that sort the keys alphabetically, not by the values numerically?

Comment: All I'm getting at is [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/182380#182380) :p

Comment: @GiovanniP [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4690094/645270) one's closer, but neither are exact duplicates.

Answer (score 28):

```
sorted(myDict, key=myDict.get, reverse=True)
```

Comment: Very condense, but it does hurt my eyes a bit ;-)

Comment: @siebz0r, although it should be done this and only this way

Comment: @gg.kaspersky That may be, but readability counts ;-)

Comment: This is about as readable as it gets.

Comment: This is actually very nice and elegant. Easy to read and to understand @siebz0r

Answer (score 8):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
>>> myDict = {'seven': 7, 'four': 4, 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'five': 5, 'eight': 8} 
>>> sorted(myDict.iterkeys(), key=lambda k: myDict[k], reverse=True)
['eight', 'seven', 'five', 'four', 'two', 'one']
```

(Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4690265/645270) answer)

It uses the built-in function `sorted` (with `reverse=True` to get highest to lowest),
and the `key` argument is a function that sets the sort key. In this case it's a lambda that fetches the corresponding dict value, but it can be pretty much anything. For example, you could use `operator.itemgetter(1)` or `myDict.get` as shown by other answers, or any other sorting function (other than by value).

Comment: No need to inverse the list, as sorted accepts a reverse parameter.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `items` to get a list of pairs key-value and `sorted` to sort them using your criteria:

```
myList = sorted(myDict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

If you're using ipython, you can type myDict.`tabtab` and you're get a list of all functions. You can also type `print myDict.items.__doc__` and get a quick documentation.

The key parameter is a function to apply to an element before it gets compared. As `items` returns a list of pairs and sorting is done on pairs' second element, key is a function which gets the second element from a tuple.

Of course, it is possible to get rid of the `items` call, using:

```
myList = sorted(myDict, key=myDict.get, reverse=True) #posted in another answer
```

Comment: `cmp` is denigrated; use `key` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the observation.

Answer (score 2):

Another variation:

```
import operator

d = {'q':2, 'x':1, 'b':10}
s = sorted(d.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

The `operator` module provides `itemgetter` which is designed to be used like this. It's faster than a lambda. ;-)

**Edit:**

I kinda misinterpreted the question. My solution returns a list of tuples (key, value) instead of just a list of strings.

As a bonus to make it up, have a look at `collections.OrderedDict`. You might also want to consider using the dict 'reversed'. e.g. switch the keys and values.

Comment: FYI, switching dictionary keys and values would be a little bizarre (and also more difficult than ordering the keys according the the values). If you wanted to do this, you probably picked the wrong data structure to begin with.