# Get the key corresponding to the 3 minimum values within a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a Python dictionary, and I want to find the keys for the 3 minimal values in it.

For example:

```
Input: d = {1 : 10 , 0.1 : 15 , 0.3 : 18 , 0.001 : 25 , 0.003 : 42}
Output: [1, 0.1 , 0.3]
```

I know how to grab only one minimum value with a list comprehension:

```
min_val = min(d.values())
min_numbers = [num for num, value in d.items() if value == min_val]
```

but how do I do it for three?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting dictionary keys based on their values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690094/sorting-dictionary-keys-based-on-their-values)

Comment: Are the min values uniq?

Comment: @mx0 No they are not.

Comment: @DeGo If I sort the dictionary, can I grab X minimal / maximal values within it?

Comment: Yes, you can slice and get the 3 minimum values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
l = [item for item in sorted(d, key=d.get)][0:3]
print(l)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 0.1, 0.3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
d = {1: 10, 0.1: 15, 0.3: 18, 0.001: 25, 0.003: 42}

for _, k in sorted([(v, k) for k, v in d.items()])[:3]:
    print(k)
```

**Output:**

```
1
0.1
0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine dictionary `items` method with `sorted` function and then filter only values with list comprehension and extract the three first results with slicing:

```py
d = {1 : 10 , 0.1 : 15 , 0.3 : 18 , 0.001 : 25 , 0.003 : 42}

min_numbers = [key for key, value in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])][:3]
```